# multiple json_object in one json_object in oracle

Tags: plsql

how can I prepare using the json with below structure using a json_object function in oracle.

```
{
  "data": {
    "input": 1450,
    "max": 7500,
    "check": 7500
  },
  "month_income": {
    "Hiring_income": 198000
  },
  "month_expense": [
    {
      "Field_input3": 45000,
      "Minimum": "Yes",
      "Check_Input": 108000,
      "Tractor_Cost": "Driver Salary"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to achieve with the below query but no luck.

```
 SELECT json_object('data' 
                            value (
                            JSON_OBJECT(
                                     'input' VALUE .50,
                                     'max' VALUE .50,
                                     'check' VALUE .50
                                        
                                        )
                                            
                                    )
                     ) 
    FROM dual;
```

Comment: Please update your question with expected json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That has been resolved.

```
SELECT json_object('data' 
                            value (
                            JSON_OBJECT(
                                     'input' VALUE .50,
                                     'max' VALUE .50,
                                     'check' VALUE .50
                                        
                                        )
                                            
                                    ),
                  'month_income' value  json_object('hiring_income' value 0.2)
                     ) 
    FROM dual;
```

I am getting the expected output using this. Here is the result of above query.

```
{
"data" : {
"input" : 0.5,
"max" : 0.5,
"check" : 0.5
},
"month_income" : {"hiring_income" : 0.2}
}
```